# Mystery with Android and notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android

My code

```
public void deleteItem(int position) {
    this.rep.open();
    this.rep.deleteEntry(this.adapter.getObject(position));
    this.adapter.deleteObjectFromList(position);
    this.rep.close();
    this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.update:
            callUpdateForm(adapter.getObject(info.position));
            this.rep.open();
            this.adapter.swapItems(this.rep.getAllEntries());
            this.rep.close();
            *** HERE ***
            return true;
        case R.id.delete:
            deleteItem(info.position);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

If I put `this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` (in *** HERE *** pointed above) my app crashes when I press delete on the context menu, without it, it works fine. But then when I update one entry it doesn't notices the change... So why does this piece of code interact when I press delete? And how to make this work ?

EDIT

I figured out that for listView to refresh it self on update I need to do it on `onResume()` event

so now my code:

```
public void deleteItem(int position) {
    this.rep.open();
    this.rep.deleteEntry(this.adapter.getObject(position));
    this.adapter.deleteObjectFromList(position);
    this.rep.close();
    this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.update:
            callUpdateForm(adapter.getObject(info.position));
            return true;
        case R.id.delete:
            deleteItem(info.position);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    this.rep.open();
    this.adapter.swapItems(this.rep.getAllEntries());
    this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    this.rep.close();
}
```

Now it updates, but on delete I got my app to crash again ... and when I remove `this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` part from `deleteItem` function it doesn't crash but it doesn't refresh my listview either...

LOGS JUST BEFORE CRASH:

```
08-02 06:13:47.566: INFO/System.out(5788): Comment deleted with id: 10
08-02 06:13:47.906: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(5788): Shutting down VM
08-02 06:13:47.906: WARN/dalvikvm(5788): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
08-02 06:13:47.916: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5788): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
    at com.example.NutritionSeeker.Adapters.EntryAdapter.getView(EntryAdapter.java:65)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1294)
    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1198)
    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

> 08-02 06:13:47.926: WARN/ActivityManager(112): Force finishing
>   activity com.example.NutritionSeeker/.HistoryActivity 08-02
>   06:13:48.488: WARN/ActivityManager(112): Activity pause timeout for
>   HistoryRecord{44f54130 com.example.NutritionSeeker/.HistoryActivity}

Comment: any logcat? will be helpful

Comment: Brother write this.rep.close below the notifydatasetchnge method

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what rep.getAllEntries does, but you should probably use an AsyncTaskLoader http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html and an Adapter attached to that. If you can help it, create a ContentProvider as your repository and use a CursorLoader instead http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html.